# Why does a vector have to move its data members when reallocating

Tags: c++, vector

Assuming that a vector contains an array internally of `std::aligned_storage` instances that actually contain elements of the type the vector is templated on if the `aligned_storage` instance is in use.

When the vector has to allocate a new block of memory and move all its elements, why does it invoke the move constructor of each element in use and then destroy the old element?  Why not just copy over all the bytes byte by byte and just delete the old array without calling destructors?  This would make the new array an exact copy of the old array without the overhead of moving and destroying elements.

Maybe I'm a little tired and am missing something really basic.  But I cannot think of a reason why this would not work.

Comment: Copying the bytes is not guaranteed to do the same thing as moving or copying the objects. For some classes it could completely break the invariants. Luckily for many types a call to the move constructor does in fact just copy the bytes, in which case compiler + optimiser will do what you want anyway.

Comment: @AlanStokes could you give me an example of such a case?  As I cannot think of one unfortunately..

Comment: I believe that if you use std::align_storage<>::type that is a template that will create initialized storage/memory blocks that can hold objects of a given type.  
As with any other uninitialized storage, the objects are created using [placement new] and destroyed with explicit destructor calls.
You could probably do what you mention in your question statement but why?  Why not use the built-in template class that you know the behavior of?  Have a look at;  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new

Comment: @Drt you mean to say why the vector cannot just have an internal array of objects of the type the vector was templated on?  If thats the case then it's because vectors guarantee that it will only construct the number of elements that you want to put in it, not for example have 2x the number of members when it reallocates, even though you wanted to only push one extra element

Comment: Not sure what you are asking but I would recommend that you have a look at:   en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new  The discussion about placement new seems to address your original question...  Ahh now i think i see...the memory is allocated for a set size and if the size is to be changed then it must be reallocated...there is no way for the OS and compiler to do otherwise

Comment: Trivial example: a class that contains a count of how many copies it is away from the original. More interesting example: class with pointers to subobjects (eg small array used as circular buffer with head and tail pointer).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would not be safe to merely copy the bytes. Imagine, for example, that your object has two members, p and d, and p is a pointer that points to d. If you just copy the bytes, you'd copy the value of p that points to the old location of d, which has been destroyed.

This is a simple example, but in general, the reason for C++ constructors, destructors, copy and move constructors, is to allow your object to be "smarter" than just a sequence of bytes would be. Member variables have meaning, and that meaning is understood by your code, not by the compiler.

Comment: Ironically, `std::vector` is itself an example of a class that does this. (Most implementations have a "small vector" optimization that inlines the allocation.) Which means that `std::vector` itself cannot be moved with `memcpy`.